# Restart animation on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some Easter animation with a little bunny that catches a falling egg. Now that's working great, but where i'm having troubles is that i can't seem to create a button that restarts my multiple animations and let's them fall/move down again once more.

I've tried alot of things this one seemed was the closest i could get but this only seemed to play/pause the whole thing and the elements would disappear after i released the hover.

```
#logo:hover ~ #ei, #otherelements{ -webkit-animation-play-state:running;  }

/* most likely the problem /*
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

But since the multiple animations move separately i kind of need the animation-iteration-count 1

Does anyone know if this is possible with just CSS or do i need to implement some javascript/jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/p5r9F/

Comment: You have to use javascript

Comment: You can start an animation by setting some value for the `animation-name` property. However it's hard to keep that `animation-name` after something fast and quick (like a click) happens. We need a long state (like `:hover`, `:focus`, `:disabled`, `:enabled`, `:checked`...) to attach the `animation-name` long enough to run the animation to the end. That means you have to keep hovering on the `#logo` long enough for the animation run to the end, after that you can try hovering again and it will run again. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/p5r9F/1/

Comment: Note that, all the `animation-name`s should be removed from the normal state of all the elements. They are only added in the `:hover` state.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy young squire (Sorry)

```
@keyframes yournameofanimation {
0% {top: 0; left: 0; background: #dda221;}
50% {top: 500px; left: 100px; background: #e0e0e0;}
100% {top: 0; left: 50px; background: grey;}
}
.nameofclass {
animation: yournameofanimation;
animation-duration: 1s; /* of course can be varied */
position: relevant;
}
.nameofclass:hover {
animation: yournameofanimation;
animation-duration: 1s; /* of course can be varied */
}
</style>
<div class="nameofclass">
<p> Try it! </p>
```